# Function parameterized with global variable

Tags: function, variables, powershell, parameters

Why can't I use a global variable as a parameter of a function....

`function Get-Diskinfo

        {param($global:Computername)
            get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk  -ComputerName $global:Computername}`

I need to reuse the variable in functions in other scripts.

Comment: In the future it helps when you explain what is wrong. Do you get unexpected results? And what are the results and why didn't you expect them? Or in this case: Do you get an error and what is the error message?

Comment: Sometimes a long question can cause reluctance to the answerer. I have seen it in many occasions. I tried to keep it short and to the point.

Thanks for pointing out though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the param block you define the names (and default values and other meta data) of the parameters your function has. $global: can't be used as a parameter name, since it defines the scope of a variable. Since you don't define variables there it makes no sense.

Do you want your function to have a computername parameter and give it the default value of a global variable? Then you can do the following.

```
function Get-Diskinfo {param($Computername = $global:Computername) 
   get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $Computername}
```

If you don't care about the parameter and always want to use the global variable you can just remove param altogether.

```
function Get-Diskinfo {
   get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $global:Computername}
```

I would not normally advise the solutions above. I find that it is better to not use global variables like this and have a script like below call different functions. This makes the code more understandable for anyone reading or debugging it. Global variables make the code difficult to understand, error prone and hard to reuse.

Function without any global variables

```
function Get-Diskinfo {param($Computername) 
   get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $Computername}
```

Script calling different functions for the same computer

```
$MyComputerName = 'client01'
Get-DiskInfo -ComputerName $MyComputerName
Get-MoreInfo -ComputerName $MyComputerName
Get-OtherInfo -ComputerName $MyComputerName
```